# how to load array of content to dictionary type

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have a array with data,i want to load the dictiionary type element with array......

```
NSArray *thisArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSSdictionary *state;
```

how to load the content with array....

any help appreciated...

Comment: Tell us what it is you're trying to do. Your question makes no sense. You want to put an array into a dictionary and persist it to a file? You want to load the contents of a file into an array? what?

Comment: i have a xml content in the file i am loading that data to array

Comment: i want to load the data to dictionary but when i was try to load is giving null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pitfall is getting the path right for the file, other than that it is pretty straight forward... if I understand the question correctly

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"someDataFile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *state = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: is not getting the data dictionary variable